# Can't create mutable sync TreeMap

Tags: kotlin

In my Kotlin project I use this:

```
private var projectsMap = mutableMapOf<Date, String?>()
```

Nice but I has sync TreeMap smt. like this:

```
private var tocanProjectsMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(TreeMap<Date, String>())
```

So how I can create **mutable synchronized TreeMap** ?

Comment: Your second expression should be sufficient. The only "problem" is carrying platform types around. Instead, you can explicitly set the type to `MutableMap<Date, String>`.

Comment: @Joffrey Do you mean this: tocanProjectsMap : MutableMap<Date, String?> = Collections.synchronizedMap(TreeMap<Date, String>() as Map<Date, String?>)  . Is it enough?

Comment: King of yes, but why do you need the cast to nullable string values?

Comment: @Joffrey I has some case, when I need to add to this map new date (key) and null (value).

Comment: @a_subscriber Why won't you just create it directly? The cast is not needed.
`MutableMap<Date, String?> = Collections.synchronizedMap(TreeMap<Date, String?>())`

Comment: @a_subscriber My point was that you can just declare the correct type directly instead of casting, like nluk said

Answer (score 3):

I can't really see the problem - Kotlin's `MutableMap` interface is descendant of `Map`. `TreeMap` itself is mutable, so the mutability depends only on type of the reference.

```
val map = Collections.synchronizedMap(TreeMap<Date, String?>()) //Mutable
var asMutable : MutableMap<Date, String?> = map //Mutable
var asImmutable : Map<Date, String?> = map //Immutable
```